# How to shut down haproxy with systemd

Tags: haproxy, systemd

I have a RHEL 7 box running HAProxy 1.5.x. I want to be able to shut it down gracefully so that keepalived can fail over to another node on the cluster and obtain the VIP. I can do this if I manually kill the process outside of systemd

```
kill -USR1 $myPid
```

However, I'd like to do this from systemd. Something like

```
systemctl kill haproxy --signal=USR1
```

But when I execute this it kills "haproxy-systemd-wrapper" as well as the haproxy instances. Is there anyway to tell it to only send the signal to the haproxy instances? I tried adding --kill-who=control, but the sub processes are apparently not control processes so it just errors out.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force method would be; killall -TERM haproxy.  I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to accomplish this.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Though I would use killall -USR1 haproxy if I wanted to use killall. I'm just curious if there was a way of doing this through systemctl.

Comment: Well what is stopping you from using "systemctl stop haproxy" ?

Comment: I want a graceful stop. Sending signal USR1 tells haproxy to finish up whatever transactions its holding on to before shutting down.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably too late to answer, but this might be helpful for those who come looking for one. This one worked for me.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop
```